# I can't uninstall Jupyter with solutions on the web

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a really weird installation of Jupyter. When I launch a notebook, Balena Etcher a USB image software loads. And when I type the link on the command line given when launching a notebook I cannot load a Python 3 runtime. What's going on?

```
(ENV) jpp@X390:~/dev$ which jupyter
/home/jpp/.local/bin/jupyter
(ENV) jpp@X390:~/dev$ pip uninstall jupyter
WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed.
(ENV) jpp@X390:~/dev$ pip3 uninstall jupyter
WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed.
(ENV) jpp@X390:~/dev$ pip-autoremove jupyter -y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpp/.local/bin/pip-autoremove", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 106, in main
    autoremove(args, yes=opts.yes)
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 21, in autoremove
    dead = list_dead(names)
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip_autoremove.py", line 28, in list_dead
    start = set(map(get_distribution, names))
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/jpp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jupyter' distribution was not found and is required by the application
(ENV) jpp@X390:~/dev$
```

Many thanks. Im about to do a fresh install of Mint if I cant get this right..

Comment: What's the output of `which pip` and `which pip3`? And are you in a virtual env right now? If so, please provide info on how did you create the virtual env and how did you install jupyter. Chances are you used `pip install --user` because it installed the package into `~/.local/bin`. There has been case of conflict when you use virtual env and `pip install --user` in conjunction, as that's not the way they're supposed to be used.

Comment: @gordon-bai I think you are right.. I do not remember how I installed jupyter.  

`jpp@X390:~$ which pip`
`/home/jpp/.local/bin/pip`
`jpp@X390:~$ which pip3`
`/usr/bin/pip3`

Comment: In that case there's always the solution to just delete jupyter package in `~/.local/bin`, sort your virtual envs, and install jupyter in a clean virtual env without using `--user` option. There's just no need to reinstall whole system as there shouldn't be other directories contaminated.

Comment: I just did that, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the package was installed with `--user` option, delete jupyter package in `~/.local/bin`.